# Is there specific form of Navier-Stokes equation for which mass can cross bounding surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes, transport-phenomena

In my textbook, we learned that Navier-Stokes (NS) equations can be derived from Reynolds transport theorem where the control volume is assumed to be fixed. But when the control volume is moving, can we derive NS equations? Will result be the same as original NS equations?
In more precise language, consider an arbitrary region $\Omega(t)$ in a fluid medium, and its bounding surface is denoted $\partial\Omega$.
Now recall Reynolds transport theorem,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x},t)\,d^3\mathbf{x}=\int_{\Omega(t)}\frac{\partial(\rho\mathbf{v})}{\partial t}\,d^3\mathbf{x}+\int_{\partial\Omega}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}_s\cdot\mathbf{n})\,d^2\mathbf{x},$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is spatial coordinates; $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of fluid; $\mathbf{v}_s$ is the velocity of segment of bounding surface. **If bounding surface doesn't coincide with the material surface**, the equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x},t)\,d^3\mathbf{x}=\bigg[\int_{\Omega(t)}\frac{\partial(\rho\mathbf{v})}{\partial t}\,d^3\mathbf{x}+\int_{\partial\Omega}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n})\,d^2\mathbf{x}\bigg]+
\int_{\partial\Omega}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}_s-\mathbf{v})\cdot\mathbf{n}\,d^2\mathbf{x}.$$
After rearrangement we obtain
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x},t)\,d^3\mathbf{x}+\int_{\partial\Omega}\rho\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}_s)\cdot\mathbf{n}\,d^2\mathbf{x}=\int_{\Omega(t)}\underbrace{\bigg[\frac{\partial(\rho\mathbf{v})}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v})\bigg]}_{\text{NS equation}}\,d^3\mathbf{x}.$$
We can recognise the right-hand side  is NS equation, does it imply that **even material can cross boundary, NS equation doesn't need any modification**?

Answer (score 4):

Given the integral continuity equation of the form,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_\Omega\phi\,\mathrm{d}\Omega+\int_\Gamma\phi\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,\mathrm{d}\Gamma-\int_\Omega s\,\mathrm{d}\Omega=0\tag{1}$$
for control volume $\Omega$, boundary $\Gamma$, $\mathbf{u}$ flow velocity, $\mathbf{n}$ normal unit, $\phi$ the integrated property (e.g., mass density) and $s$ sources or sinks. One then invokes the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the [Reynolds transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem) to obtain,
$$\int_\Omega\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left(\phi\mathbf{u}\right)+s\right)\,\mathrm{d}\Omega=0\tag{2}$$
Since $\Omega$ is entirely arbitrary, then Eq (2) must be true for *any* control volume, hence the integrand is what must be equal to zero. This relation is still true even if the control volume is moving.

Note that this is stated in the first section of the Wikipedia entry on [*Derivation of the Navier-Stokes equations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Basic_assumptions),

> Sometimes it is necessary to consider a finite arbitrary volume, called a control volume, over which these principles can be applied.... The control volume can remain fixed in space or can move with the fluid.

If you are considering a case wherein the mass can escape $\Omega$, then you do *not* have a control volume (as the very definition of the control volume requires a constant mass). In such a case, then you end up with an additional term when applying the time derivative onto the first integral of Eq (1),
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_{\Omega}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\Omega=\int_\Omega\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\,\mathrm{d}\Omega+\int_\Gamma C\phi\,\mathrm{d}\Gamma$$
where $C$ is the [velocity of the interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_moving_surfaces) (see also [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_evolution_of_integrals#Volume_integrals)). Which means that the derivation would result in a Navier-Stokes-*like* equation, rather than the Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. To fully understand this, I borrowed a book _nonlinear finite elements for continua and structures_. In their derivation, deformation gradient and Jacobian are used. But I don't know how $\frac{DJ}{Dt}=J\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$, where $J=\det{F}$ and $F$ is the deformation gradient.

Comment: @106207436 That looks to be a separate question ("how is this derivation completed", may or may not be on topic) from the original question ("does NS hold for moving CV"). Please ask it separately if it is indeed a question; if it's supposed to follow this, I think you might need to edit how it applies to your current question (because I don't currently see the relation).

Comment: hello, I edited my question to make it more precise. I tried to prove it and obtain a result that may coincide with the explanation you said (I'm not sure.)

Comment: The derivation of the NS from the continuity integral using Reynold's transport & divergence theorems is the *same* whether you invoke a constant or a time-dependent control volume. I'm not sure what more you are looking for than that.

Comment: sorry for my ambiguous expression. I mean, consider a case for which $\Omega(t)$ moves and its surface doesn't coincide with material surface (i.e. material can cross its surface so mass enclosed within $\Omega(t)$ may change). Even so, NS equation still doesn't need any modification?

Comment: The definition of control volume requires that the mass contained in $\Omega(t)$ be constant. If you are considering a case where it is not, then you do not have a control volume & you probably cannot get back to Navier Stokes.

Comment: @106207436 I've added a new remark about the escaping mass scenario. You do **not** get NS in the end.